# XMPP - What is different between muc (mod_muc) and mucLight (mod_muc_light)?

Tags: ejabberd, multiuserchat, mongoose-im

I have successfully implemented **mucLight** in my app with **mongooseIM** server.but I'm aware about **muc** protocol on **ejabberd** server.

Which client extension support muc/mucLight protocol ?

Is there a way to have a shared history for a group using muc/mucLight protocol ?

Which is improved for mobile devices ?

any others pros and cons ?

Answer (score 2):

> Which client extension support muc/mucLight protocol ?

MUC is supported by almost every client library, MUC Light is supported by Smack and XMPPFramework. Also, MUC Light may be configured to use MUC protocol (with some MUC Light-exclusive features unavailable).

> Is there a way to have a shared history for a group using muc/mucLight protocol ?

In MongooseIM both MUC and MUC Light use the same extension and table for archiving so theoretically their archives should be compatible but it is not a requirement so is not tested automatically in the project.

> Which is improved for mobile devices ?

MUC Light exchanges data much less frequently than MUC and the packets attempt to carry information as efficiently as possible to reduce round-trips and unnecessary traffic.

> any others pros and cons ?

http://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/open-extensions/muc_light/#2-requirements

Here are the high-level principles behind MUC Light, that more or less directly indicate differences.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fZ3iQ752Tk
I explained it once and it has been recorded.